# How to verify if there is some information in the stdin buffer in ANSI C in a portable way?

Tags: c, input, user-input, portability, ansi-c

I'm trying to develop a portable function in ANSI C that verifies if the stdin buffer is empty. The idea is to use it to verify if the user has pressed some key.

In windows, it is easy to do that using kbhit (from conio.h), but it is OS dependent.

However, I'd like to develop my own portable function.

Comment: Would a POSIX way be acceptable?

Comment: "In windows, it is easy to do that using kbhit (from conio.h)" nooo. Stop using conio.h!

Comment: Detecting if key is pressed requires some iteration with keyboard driver. This is out of scope of any c standard

Comment: Sorry to hear you're stuck with ANSI C in 2021.

Comment: @bolov This is a pet peeve of mine: If someone is doing X, and it's working for them, don't just say "don't do X" without also saying "do Y instead".

Comment: Code can find out what the next letter is and put it back, but not detect beforehand if it is there.

Comment: "In windows, it is easy to do that using kbhit (from conio.h), but it is OS dependent." --> It is not an OS issue, but a primarily a compiler one.

Answer (score 2):

Neither ANSI C nor the current C standard provides a way to do this. It can only be done using implementation-specific extensions.