# How to detect if the user has pressed some key, in a portable way, in a non-blocking way, without changing the content of the stdin buffer?

Tags: c, input, user-input, portability

I'd like to make a cross-platform (portable) game in standard C.
For doing that, I need a non-blocking way for detecting if the user has pressed some key, without changing the content of the stdin buffer.

I'd like to encapsulate that in a function hasPressedKey. I would like to use it, in the following way:

```
if(hasPressedKey()){
    c = <read a char from the stdin buffer>
    <do something with c>   
}
```

The idea is that the hasPressedKey() function does not block the program flow. Is none key is pressed, the program follows in a regular way. If some key is pressed, I'd like to deal with it in a suitable way.

I know that the kbhit function in conio.h does something like this. But it is not portable.
Is there any way to implement something like this in a portable way?

Comment: Short and only answer is that there is no portable way, it's all OS specific.

Comment: There was a question on this a few days ago. OP was using `kbhit` under WinX and wanting a portable way. There is _no_ portable way using `stdin`. For Linux/POSIX, you can bypass `stdin` and deal directly with fd 0. You use `termios` to put the _kernel_ TTY layer into "raw" mode. Then, you can do: `ioctl(0,FIONREAD)` to poll the number of characters.

Comment: @CraigEstey: [Same user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67170391/how-to-verify-if-there-is-some-information-in-the-stdin-buffer-in-ansi-c-in-a-po/67171215#67171215).

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did a search for `kbhit` and last 7 days looking for that question and came back empty ... Thanks

Comment: It is not a duplicate question. In the other question I was asking for some method for verifying the buffer of the stdin. In this one I'm asking for some general method for detecting key pressing. Maybe there is some way to do that without checking information in the buffer of stdin.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Standard C has no concept of keyboards, only of input streams.  Detecting key presses is inherently implementation-dependent.

There are of course various third-party libraries you could use, that may have been ported to a variety of systems.